# Why str(0.20) = 0.2 instead of 0.20 in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to convert a float 0.20 to a string using

```
str(0.20)
```

However, what I got was '0.2' instead of '0.20'. Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried to search on Google and stackoverflow, but I didn't find any useful answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `str` doesn't know your formating requirements - us `format`, e.g. `format(0.2, '.2f')`

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Comment: The value of the float is 0.2. As far as the float is concerned, there is no difference between 0.2 and 0.20. If you want to format the string a particular way, you'll need to use a formatter. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: It's not only in python, but in any language. I believe you could specify the precision somehow, when converting a number to a string - I don't know much about python, but in several languages you can do such a thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's string formatting functionality.
Actually there are three possibilities:

- f-strings, since python 3.6

  ```
  value = 0.2
  print(f'{value:.2f}') # 2 digits precision
  ```
- `str.format`

  ```
  value = 0.2
  print('{:.2f}'.format(value))
  ```
- % formatting

  ```
  value = 0.2
  print('%.2f' % value)
  ```

For more formatting details, see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec) that allows you to format an number in a pre-defined way. To say that you want to format a floating point number and have two digits after the separator, use `.2f`:

```
data = 0.20

print("{0:.2f}".format(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question in the title is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/547270) about `__str__`: it is because `str` is for readability, so its aim is to produce *nice* output rather than *precise* one.